# Upgrading to Django 3.1.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Just upgraded from Django version 3.0.3 to 3.1.2. When trying to run the server, I am now presented with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 70, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/turbz/work/z/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 200, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS/PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT are mutually exclusive.
```

I have neither of those aforementioned settings set in my own `settings.py`, since they are coming from `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings.py`. So I dont understand where its coming from. Setting one for them manually now also doesnt make the error go away. Im not overriden it myself according to https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/2962/ht9zvG.png
& https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/2198/zfk5xo.png

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue. I was import

```
from django.conf.global_settings import *
```

in `settings.py` for some stupid reason.

Answer (score 0):

> I have neither of those aforementioned settings set in my own settings.py, **since they are coming from** venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings.py.

You have misdiagnosed the problem.  The code that throws that exception checks to see if you have *explicitly overridden* both of the default settings defined in `global_settings.py`.

The code (which is in the `django.conf.Settings.__init__` method) looks like this:

```
    if self.is_overridden('PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS'):
        if self.is_overridden('PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT'):
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                'PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS/PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT are '
                'mutually exclusive.'
            )
```

I suspect that your configs are somehow overriding these parameters somewhere else.

Comment: But thats the thing. I have not. I have never set this setting anywhere. They can be found in `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py` and `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/global_settings.py` and ofc in `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py` EDIT: stubs also sets it `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django-stubs/conf/global_settings.pyi`

Comment: for more info: https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img922/2962/ht9zvG.png / https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/2198/zfk5xo.png